# Email queue processing

Tags: node.js, email, transactions, queue

I'm wanting to create a process by which I can better integrate incoming emails into my application workflow.

I want to have incoming emails picked up by my system, processed and added to an internal "queue" (added to a data store). This pickup and save needs to happen as a transaction, as I don't want to loose emails.

Currently the email account in question is a google apps email, but I'm happy to switch it over to something else.

I'm just wondering what architecture/setup people would recommend for this? I would prefer not to have to host my own SMTP server but will if thats the way I need to go and would prefer not to reinvent the wheel if I don't have to.

My current thinking is to maybe us mandrill and a webhook, but I'm wondering if there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer more service based solution, then here it is:

- You could use the RabbitMQ for scalable queue solution.
- Amazon simple email service (SES) for sending emails, the price for sending 1k emails was about $0.10.
- Nodemailer as the client in Node.js

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In this case, its more about processing the incoming emails rather than the outgoing ones.